# How can I use scrollView inside collectionViewCell with dynamic size

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

I want to create this page. And I created a collectionView inside viewController. But how can I make the height of this dynamic and i think i need to create a scroll view? How do I change the collection view size than json data loaded? And how should the structure on this page?

I created programmatically collection view but I don't have any data now. But when I create collection view I have to give height value. I must when I loaded json data than I will set frame details. Please help this topics.. At least give mind please.. Thank you all

Edit:

I added scroll view inside cell but switch between cells not working now. In red area(cell) working switching but not working on containerView..

[Scroll View problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygBYd.png)

```
class NewsDetailController: UIViewController {

private lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: view.frame.width, height: 800)
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.isPagingEnabled = true
    cv.delegate = self
    cv.dataSource = self
    cv.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    cv.register(NewsDetailCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    return cv
}()

// MARK: - Lifecycle

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureUI()
    
}
// MARK: - Helpers

func configureUI() {

    view.addSubview(collectionView)
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    
    view.addSubview(stackBottomButtons)
    stackBottomButtons.anchor(left: view.leftAnchor,bottom: view.bottomAnchor,right: view.rightAnchor,paddingLeft: 16,paddingBottom: 32,paddingRight: 16, height: 60)
    backButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    shareButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    
}

 }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! NewsDetailCell

    return cell
}

}

extension NewsDetailController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 800)
}
}

class NewsDetailCell: UICollectionViewCell {

// MARK: - Properties

let contentLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    return label
}()

// MARK: - Lifecycle

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    configure()
    configureUI()
}

func configure() {
    contentLabel.text = articleViewModel?.article.content
}

func configureUI() {

    addSubview(contentLabel)
    contentLabel.anchor(top: stack.bottomAnchor,left: leftAnchor,right: rightAnchor)

}

}
```

[I want to make this page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WclwB.jpg)

[Full Code](https://github.com/alperentoksoz/NewsAppClone---sondakika-)

Answer (score 0):

[I think you are looking for something like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EcffhZbHHmk)

To make the frame size dynamic you you need to set the cell size by the attributes combined height inside of the cells this can be done in the customCell file you create using this link

Comment: Dummy thank you for answer. This is very helpful for me. I created scroll view inside cell. And a container view inside scroll view. But switch between cells not working now..